# Nginx proxy_reverse and node server. Where do you see the console log OUTPUT from upstream NODE server?

Tags: node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I come from windows server world. First time to use Nginx and so far, it's impressive but I have an issue and that's why I'm here ;)

I've Ubuntu 20.04, Nginx and deployed an expressjs app (node), followed all the tutorials out there to setup Nginx and a proxy_reverse server. It works and I'm able to see and run/interact with my expressjs app routes (home, signin, signup...etc)

My only issue is I can't see the results of console.log I placed in my routes (my node server) Get route example :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.log("db is connected, user is loggedin and we're ready to 
                      go....wait...another issue with Nginx I need to research and I can't 
                      find in the docs")
        res.send('hello world')
})
```

How do I view the result of that route if my node server is behind the Nginx server? Is there a way that makes Nginx display those logs to me (the admin)?

There are trillions of tutorials out there about how to add nginx as proxy but not one of them talk about this important issue. If you have a link that I can read or if you're experienced enough with Nginx proxy_reverse log operations, please explain in details or show me in code how do you view the console.log from the expressjs routes.

So, my question is how do I see that console.log in the example above output? Is it Nginx parameter, here is my server setup /etc/nginx/sites-available/default (I deleted irrelevant parts):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
        
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _; 
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Is there a directive in the context of location/server that I need to allow passing logs from the node/expressjs server to nginx shell or to anywhere to see what's going on with node/express routes? Is it in the nginx logs somewhere that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone starting with this stack, pm2 logs when you inside your app directory will print logs to your console.

```
my_app_directory  pm2 logs
```